# MDB Maillistener @ActivationConfigProperty for SSL

Tags: java, email, ssl, pop3, message-driven-bean

We have a MDB which is rading emails from an email account, the MDB implements MailListener interface and I'm looking for a property to enable POP3 via SSL

i have the settings in xml like this, below, I nead an aditional  activation-config-property for the port and for the SSL ... I've googled it but no success, can anyone help here?

I'm using jboss5.1, seam2

```
    <message-driven>
        <description>An MDB that accepts mail messages</description>
        <ejb-name>MailListenerMDB</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailListener.MailListenerMDB</ejb-class>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>userName</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>******</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>password</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>********</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>pollingInterval</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>15000</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>mailServer</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>*****</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>mailFolder</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>INBOX</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>storeProtocol</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>pop3</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
</message-driven>
```

Comment: @HansUp sory it was a typo, i've changed it to massege-driven-bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution you nead to specify those properties

```
<activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>storeProtocol</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>pop3s</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>port</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>995</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
               <activation-config-property-name>starttls</activation-config-property-name>
               <activation-config-property-value>true</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
```

be careful especiali for the protocol which is POP3S and not POP3